# How to pass props to <Link> in React Router? React.js, javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have this code here. On click of button, the `lat` and `lon` gets passed to a method called `getFood` which expects the params of `lat` and `lon` to make the right API call based on the location.

```
     <button
            onClick={() => this.props.onClick(meetup.venue.lat, meetup.venue.lon)}>
            <Link to="/restaurants">Find Restaurants</Link>
     </button>
```

How can I pass `this.props.onClick(meetup.venue.lat, meetup.venue.lon)` into my `<Link to="/restaurants">Find Restaurants</Link>` ?

The user would have to click on the button, and THEN the link to 1) make the api call based on the location and then 2) to render the new component. Of course this is bad UX so I would like to not have the button element all together, if possible.

On my restaurants component, I can make the API call on `componentDidMount` however, I would still need the location.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In Link you can pass your data in state key and retrive it in a component which will load on /forgot-password route.

```
<Link 
    className="link-text-color"
    to={{
         pathname: "/forgot-password",
         state: { modal: true, returnTo:this.props.location.pathname}
       }}
>
forgot password
</Link>
```

the state object will retrive using

> props.history.location.state

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
<Link to={`/restaurants/${meetup.venue.lat},${meetup.venue.lon}`}>Find Restaurants</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-router` v2 you could pass the location with the URL query string by using the `<Link to={object} />` notation ([Docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object)). See example below:

```
<Link to={{
    pathname: '/restaurants',
    search: `?lat=${meetup.venue.lat}&lon=${meetup.venue.lon}`
}} />
```

Within your `Restaurants` component you can access those properties within the `props.history` object (Example: `history.location.search`)